# verify interaction in spock not working

Tags: groovy, spock

I have a spock test similar to this:

```
def "test" () {
    given:
        def mockOutput = new Output()
        Service mockService = Mock()
        classUnderTest.service = mockService
        mockService.method(_, "some string") >> mockOutput

    when:
        def returnedObject = classUnderTest.run()

    then:
        1* mockService.method(_, "some string")
}
```

I am trying to verify an method call of a service inside a class but it does not work.

Based on my debugging, the stubbed call that is suppose to return mockOutput is not working anymore.

However, I am successful when Im asserting the returnedObject which is the mockOutput (with exactly the same given and when blocks):

Note that the returned object of the service is the returnObject of the class calling it.

```
    then:
        returnedObject instanceof Output
        returnedObject != null
```

What am I missing?

Comment: What is the error message you're getting?

Comment: The statement `def mockService = Mock()` does not make sense. How should Spock know what kind of mock object to create?

Comment: you are right, My Bad. I'll fix it

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found what is wrong.

When trying to verify the interaction with a stubbed method, you should include the interaction return values in the 'then' block

```
then:
    1* mockService.method(_, "some string") >> mockOutput
```

Comment: You can just as well put the interaction into the `given` block. The important point is that mocking and stubbing of the same method call needs to be done in the same interaction. You can't split it up as in your initial post. This is further explained in the [docs](http://docs.spockframework.org).